# unit test for api mvc run fails and debug works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, unit-testing, web-api-testing

I have the next UnitTest definition for testing a controller in Api web MVC project:

```
public class PersonsControllerTest
{
    Api.Controllers.PersonsController controller;
    IPersonsRepository repository;

    public PersonsControllerTest()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            ProjectPersons.Model.MapConfiguration.Configure(cfg);
        });

        this.repository = ProjectPersons.Model.ProjectPersonsServiceLocator.Get<IPersonsRepository>();
        this.controller = new Api.Controllers.PersonsController(repository);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPersons()
    {
        IEnumerable<PersonsVO> response = controller.index();

        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
        //Assert.IsInstanceOfType(response, GetType(IEnumerable<PersonsVO>));            
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreatePerson()
    {
        string name = "Juan Perez";
        string about = "Gran Empleado";

        PersonsVO person = new PersonsVO()
        {
            Name = name,
            About = about,
        };

        IHttpActionResult response = controller.add(person);

        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
        Assert.IsTrue((response.GetType() == typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<PersonsVO>)));

        PersonsVO personCreated = ((OkNegotiatedContentResult<PersonsVO>)response).Content;

        Assert.AreEqual(name, personCreated.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(about, personCreated.About);
    }
}
```

When I Run the Test, CreatePerson() it fails, but if I debug the Test CreatePerson() it works.

Any idea? When I run the test, the Assert that Fails is Assert.IsTrue((response.GetType() == typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult))), but if I debug the test, that Assert is valid.

The add method is something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult add(PersonsVO person)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if ( person.Id == null || person.Id == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    person.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                }

                try
                {
                    if (personsRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Id == person.Id).Any())
                    {
                        PersonsVO personToUpdate = personsRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Id == person.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                        personToUpdate.Name = person.Name;
                        personToUpdate.About = person.About;

                        personsRepository.Update(personToUpdate);

                        return Ok(personToUpdate);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        personsRepository.Add(person);
                        return Ok(person);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest("One or more fields are incorrect");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

        }
```

Best regards...

Comment: show the method under test. under what scenario can the action return another response type?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: This also looks more like an integration test based on the arrangement of the test rather than a unit test.

Comment: I edited the post, wich the method that fails on run...

Comment: When it fails on run check to see what the actual return type is. That will help  narrow down true failure point

Comment: You may want to use lock objects to test a database operations

Comment: Nkosi: that is that I want, but if a DEBUG the test, the test NOT FAIL

Comment: So? Write some code that will log the value, that will run regardless of whether you're debugging it or running it as a test.